# Twilio get recording from call object

Tags: php, twilio

I want to get the recording (URI) from the call object (JSON), these are all the calls on the account:

```
$this->log = $this->client->calls->read();
```

I am looping through them like:

```
foreach($this->log as $call) {
    echo $call->duration;
}
```

Output 5, 10 ect. If I change duration to `recordings` it doesn't work, why?

The docs are so useless, it doesn't say anything about this.. I can see the Recordings URI in the object but I dont know how to access it the "Twilio" way. (or any other way..)

https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/rest/call#instance-subresources-recordings

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

[Recordings](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/rest/recording) isn't a property on a [Call](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/rest/call), they are a subresource. So, you need to make another call to the API. So, to get the Recordings you'd need to do the following:

```
foreach($this->log as $call) {
    foreach($call->recordings->read() as $recording) {
      echo $recording->uri;
   }
}
```

Sorry about your experience with the documentation. I will feed this back to the team so that we can hopefully improve this for the future.

Comment: Thank you, that works. However, it is taking 8 seconds to load the 10 recordings now. Is it possible in another way to do less of those $call->recording->read() requests?

Comment: This will take a long time as it is making a request to the API for each call. I actually recommend using the [recording status webhooks](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/twiml/record#attributes-recording-status-callback) that you can set on each [recording method](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/rest/recording) to receive the recording details when they are ready and save the URLs and other data to your own local database. This saves hitting the API many times and means you can optimise the data for your usage.